# How to generate gradle run configs in intellij?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft

How to generate `runClient` and `runServer`?
I downloaded sources of TheQuarkMod for 1.16.5 from GitHub and I don't know how can I generate run configs in IntelliJ.

Using Windows 10 and Java 8 (for this project - I have Installed Java 15 [or maybe Java 14 or Java 16])?

Comment: so, you are using a professional IDE, while you don't even know what Java version you have installed, let alone are using. You download source code without knowing what to do with it? I would recommend starting with the basics of Java first, and figuring out all of the essential stuff before trying to apply it to advanced material

Comment: I know java. I don't know the version of java i'm using to run other people's things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `apply plugin: 'idea'` under `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` in the `build.gradle`.

Then you can use `gradlew genIntellijRuns` to generate the runs, `gradlew idea` to create an Intellij project and `gradlew openIdea` to open it.

Use `./gradlew` if you are using a UNIX-based System.

Comment: Thanks! that command was exactly what I searched for!